# Excel macro to print varying numbers of copies of multiple sheets

Tags: excel, printing, vba

I have an excel workbook that contains multiple sheets. In this workbook sheets occasionally are removed, renamed, or added. This workbook features a sheet (Sheet1) that is supposed to be used as a command center for printing copies of the other sheets in the workbook. Unfortunately, this printing command center does not work as intended.

The command center has only two columns. In column A is a list with the names of the other Sheets. In column B the user can specify how many copies to print of the respective sheet in column A.

This is the current code:

```
Sub PrintSheets()
    Dim mysheets As Range
    For Each mySheets In Sheet1.Range("A2:A100")
    If mySheets.Offset(0, 1).Value <> "" Then Sheets(mySheets.Value).PrintOut Copies:=mySheets.Offset(0, 1).Value
    Next mySheets
End Sub
```

The first two sheets are printed as intended and then I get a "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range"

1) How can I fix the error?

2) Can the list with the sheet names be generated automatically and sorted by their position (i.e., left to right in the sheet tab -> top to bottom in the column)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you rename, add and remove sheets, you will have to update your list before printing. This sub will clear `Range("A2:A100")` and it will insert all sheets names in your first sheet. Make sure your "command center" sheet is the first one (or change the index reference to the name of that special sheet).

```
Sub LIST_SHEETS()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Byte
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2:A100").Clear

i = 2

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A" & i).Value = ws.Name
    i = i + 1
Next ws
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I'm afraid you will have to figure out where to put the code. I don't know your needs, so maybe after renaming/adding/deleting all sheets, or maybe when Workbook opens or something like that. Try it!.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that a name in the list of sheets, does not exactly match the actual name. You can use either of the two options below, to loop through each sheet

```
For Each sht in ThisWorkbook.Sheets
     'Do Something
Next
```

Or

```
Dim sht as Worksheet
    For i= 0 to ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    Set sht=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i)
    'Do something
Next
```

The second option is not reliable when the sheets are deleted (their integer index may not be sequential then) so I would prefer the first option.

Comment: I am not exactly sure how to implement this. If I refer to the sheets this way, how can I combine this with the individual numbers of copies (input in column B on Sheet1 in the workbook) that I should be printed?

Comment: You can get the name of each sheet using `sht.Name` or `ActiveSheet.Name`. Look for it in the list in Sheet1 and get the corresponding number of copies.